# How to run a python script in Bamboo server?

Tags: python-3.x, continuous-integration, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts, bamboo-specs

I'm new to Devop's field. I wanted to run python script using bamboo server. Can anyone help me with the proper Documentation or any steps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be much more specific here:

- Do you have Bamboo Project/Plan ready?
- Do you want to run the script on a remote PC? If so, do you have a Bamboo Agent installed on the PC?

If you have all of the above ready, just create a Job in your Plan. Then create a Task of Builder/Script type. Simplest example of the Script Task would be as on the following screenshot:
[bamboo task to run a python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5gRv.png)